# Animating alpha to 0 doesn't function properly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uilabel, uianimation

I have a couple of animations in my app that involve changing the alpha value of different objects. These work great for fading the object in, but they never seem to work for fading to 0.

```
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4,
            delay: 0,
            options: .CurveLinear & .AllowUserInteraction & .BeginFromCurrentState,
            animations: {
                cell.notesLabel.alpha = 0
            }, completion: nil)
```

Basically, the transparency just switches straight for 100% to 0% instantly. If I increase the duration, it just takes longer to start the animation and then it does it instantly again.

Anyone have any ideas?

Entire Code:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as CustomTransactionTableViewCell
        if cell.notesLabel.alpha == 100 {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4,
                delay: 0,
                options: .CurveLinear | .AllowUserInteraction | .BeginFromCurrentState,
                animations: {
                    cell.notesLabel.alpha = 0
                }, completion: { (finished:Bool) in
                    UIView.animateWithDuration(1,
                        delay: 0,
                        options: .CurveLinear & .AllowUserInteraction & .BeginFromCurrentState,
                        animations: {
                            cell.paymentArrowImage.frame.origin.x = cell.paymentArrowImage.frame.origin.x - 400
                            cell.creditArrowImage.frame.origin.x = cell.creditArrowImage.frame.origin.x - 400
                            cell.paymentNameLabel.frame.origin.x = cell.paymentNameLabel.frame.origin.x + 400
                            cell.dateLabel.frame.origin.x = cell.dateLabel.frame.origin.x + 400
                            cell.costLabel.frame.origin.x = cell.costLabel.frame.origin.x - 400
                        }, completion: nil)
            })
        } else {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4,
                delay: 0,
                options: .CurveLinear & .AllowUserInteraction & .BeginFromCurrentState,
                animations: {
                    cell.paymentArrowImage.frame.origin.x = cell.paymentArrowImage.frame.origin.x + 400
                    cell.creditArrowImage.frame.origin.x = cell.creditArrowImage.frame.origin.x + 400
                    cell.costLabel.frame.origin.x = cell.costLabel.frame.origin.x + 400
                    cell.paymentNameLabel.frame.origin.x = cell.paymentNameLabel.frame.origin.x - 400
                    cell.dateLabel.frame.origin.x = cell.dateLabel.frame.origin.x - 400
                    cell.notesLabel.alpha = 100
                }, completion: nil)
        }
```

Comment: Is cell a collection or table view cell?  That could account for some surprising results.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with different options to see if those are causing unexpected results? I would start off with simply `.CurveLinear` and go from there.

Comment: @danh It's a table view cell but this is a problem outside of cells too. I've used the same animation in standard views before.

Comment: You need to use `|` instead of `&` between the options.

Comment: @Kevin That doesn't seem to make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: try with .CurveEaseInOut instead of .CurveLinear

Comment: @user3746428 The other locations for the options still use the &'s instead of |'s.

Comment: @0x7fffffff That's new info. Might have something to do with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using 0 to 100 as your alpha values, when they are expected to be values from 0.0 to 1.0. This is causing your condition to malfunction as well as causing the animation issues.

Answer (score 2):

Your options currently are `.CurveLinear & .AllowUserInteraction & .BeginFromCurrentState`

These options are actually bit-shifted values, so they are represented by `001`, or `010`, or `100`, and so on.

When you `&` them together, you are actually testing to see which bits they all share in common. `001 % 010` returns `00`, because where a 1 is found in one, a 0 is in the either.

What you want is to `|` (or) them together. This makes it so that if a 1 is found in that place value for *any* of the numbers, it is found in the answer. For example, `010 | 001` returns `011`.

For your code, you really want `.CurveLinear | .AllowUserInteraction | .BeginFromCurrentState`.

Comment: For some reason, that doesn't seem to fix it. I'll update my original question with the rest of my code so you can see if their is anything obvious wrong with it.

Comment: Although this doesn't fix the problem you reported, erdekhayser is still correct that this is a problem in your code.